# How do get user input from <input> created using *ngFor in which number of input depends upon the length of json response in angular 7

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-forms, dynamicform, angular-formbuilder

Create dynamic dropdown input in html using Angular 7 depending upon JSON response

I'm getting a json response from backend, depending upon response i created labels and dropdown input in html, but now i want user to set some value for each label using dropdown input, and i want to create a json object for that given input to pass it back to post call

```
<tr *ngFor = "let storeData of storeDatas; let i = index" >
  <th scope="row"> {{storeData}} </th>
    <td> 
        <select class="form-control" >
            <option>Market</option>
            <option>Store ID</option>
            <option>Time Points</option>
            <option>Channel</option>
            <option>Sub Channel</option>
            <option>Category Sales</option>
            <option>Brand</option>
            <option>Subbrand</option>
            <option>Sales</option>
            <option>Items</option>
            <option>Unit</option>
            <option>Demographic</option> 
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to take dropdown input from user for each label, and pass it as a json to a post call.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the selected value of the select to a model value, like this:

```
<select [(ng-model)]="selectedName">
    <option value="storeID">Store ID</option>
    <option value="timePoints">Time Points</option>
</select>
```

Then in your typescript code you can just create a post call and send your class variables.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-model' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("              <th scope="row">{{storeData}}</th>
                  <td><select class="form-control" [ERROR ->][(ng-model)]="selectedName">
                      <option>Market</option>
                      <opt"): ng:///ProjectManagementModule/ProjectDetailComponent.html@49:51

Comment: It is ```ngModel``` and not ```ng-model```